# Can I make text in a div act like a button? I'd like to transform the y 4px on clicking the div

Tags: html, css

I have the color of the div changing on hover but now I want to have it have a push button effect when I click it (offset the y 4px) but I cant get it to work. Do I have to make the div a link or something? I want to use the same div later to save text to local storage. Do I just need to make it a button instead?

Comment: Checkout addEventListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: It helps if you post some of your code in your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Check out the :active pseudo-class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

```
.button:active {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```